# How do I invert matplotlib bars at a specific point instead of when negative?

Tags: matplotlib

I'd like to invert the bars in this diagram when they are below 1, not when they are negative. Additionally I'd like to have even spacing between the ticks/steps on the y-axis

Here is my current code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

labels = ['A','B','C']

Vals1 = [28.3232, 12.232, 9.6132]
Vals2 = [0.00456, 17.868, 13.453]
Vals3 = [0.0032, 1.234, 0.08214]

x = np.arange(len(labels)) 
width = 0.2 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width, Vals1, width, label='V1')
rects2 = ax.bar(x, Vals2, width, label='V2')
rects3 = ax.bar(x + width, Vals3, width, label='V3')

ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels) 
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
ax.legend()
yScale = [0.0019531,0.0039063,0.0078125,0.015625,0.03125,0.0625,0.125,0.25,0.5,1,2,4,8,16,32]
ax.set_yticks(yScale)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I believe I've stumbled upon the answer, here it is for anyone else looking for the solution. Add the argument bottom='1' to ax.bar instantiation, and then flip the values in the array.

```
for i in range(len(Vals1)):
    Vals1[i] = (1 - Vals1[i]) * -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, the key is the `bottom` param of [`Axes.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html):

> **`bottom`** (default: 0): The y coordinate(s) of the bars bases.

But beyond that, you can simplify your plotting code using pandas:

1. Put your data into a `DataFrame`:

   ```py
   import pandas as pd
   df = pd.DataFrame({'V1': Vals1, 'V2': Vals2, 'V3': Vals3}, index=labels)

   #         V1        V2       V3
   # A  28.3232   0.00456  0.00320
   # B  12.2320  17.86800  1.23400
   # C   9.6132  13.45300  0.08214
   ```
2. Then use [`DataFrame.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) to subtract the offset and [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) with the `bottom` param:

   ```py
   bottom = 1
   ax = df.sub(bottom).plot.bar(bottom=bottom)
   ```

   [image: pandas bar plot with bottom setting]